# Rbenv says the ruby version has changed but when I try to bundle says Im on the wrong version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Yeah, I've got no idea what's going on here is it because the 2.2.0 version is inside the 2.2.3 version? I've tried removing the ruby version and reinstalling with rbenv but still is in the same directory.

[ruby -v, rbenv local, rbenv global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke5mm.png)

[ruby env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4mul.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Here's a link to the command's description:

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash

Comment: Yeah closed terminal and now bundle is working but do those paths look right at all? I feel like they're in the wrong place.

Comment: Your paths look dead on to me. Basically identical to mine.